# http request with status 200 but no response data

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, httpresponse

I am trying to make an http request on refresh within my Angular frontend to a nodejs backend and expect to receive a token as response. Sometimes the request gets cancelled and even if its successful (200) i do not get send the token in the response.

When i make a postman request the request is always successful and sends the token, also when i make the request in Angular constructor without the refresh logic, so i suspect it has something to do with the usage of rxjs but can not figure out whats the problem.

here is the logic of refresh in app.component

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
private auth: AuthService
) {
// this.auth.requestServer(ServerMethod.GET, '/refresh').subscribe() // this request would work fine

router.events.pipe(
  switchMap((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      const browserRefresh = !router.navigated;
      if (browserRefresh) {
        this.auth.deleteAccessToken();
        return this.auth.requestServer(ServerMethod.GET, '/refresh');
      }
    }
    return EMPTY;
  })
).subscribe();
}
```

here is deleteAccessToken()

```
deleteAccessToken() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    this.tokenSubject.next(null);
  }
```

requestServer()

```
  requestServer(type: ServerMethod, path?: string, data?: any): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions: httpOptions;
    switch (type) {
      case ServerMethod.POST:
        return this.server.post(path, data).pipe(tap(res => this.handleAccessToken(res)));
      case ServerMethod.GETALL:
        return this.server.getAll(this.getAllPath);
      case ServerMethod.GET:
        return this.server.get(path).pipe(tap(res => this.handleAccessToken(res)));
      default:
        return EMPTY;
    }
  }
```

here is server get method

```
get(path: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.serverAdress + path;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

and in my nodejs backend here is the refresh logic:

```
module.exports.refresh_get = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.cookies && req.cookies.refreshToken) {

        // Destructuring refreshToken from cookie
        const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;

        // Verifying refresh token
        jwt.verify(refreshToken, 'secret',
            (err, decodedToken) => {
                if (err) {

                    // Wrong Refesh Token
                    res.status(406).json({ message: 'wrong refresh token' });
                }
                else {
                    // create new accessToken
                    const accessToken = createToken(decodedToken.id);
                    // create new refreshToken and set it in cookie and delete old cookie
                    const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign({
                        id: decodedToken.id,
                    }, 'secret', { expiresIn: '1d' });
                    res.cookie('refreshToken', newRefreshToken, { httpOnly: true,
                        sameSite: 'None', secure: true,
                        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
                    res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
                }
            })
    } else {
        res.status(406).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
}
```

request in network tab on refresh looks then like this:
[image]

but Response is empty, there should be an object { accessToken: '...' }

Comment: have you tried adding a log inside your backend code? what is the method call sequence?

Comment: the backend code gets executed and it sends the status 200 back. only the response of the accessToken is missing. i dont know if there should be any other methods called in the backend code after that?

Comment: there is a small error in your code but it's probably not the cause: `if (browserRefresh) {} else { return EMPTY; }` add the else clause.  That said, add a console.log() on the server and on the client to see if the accessToken is present or not

Comment: yeah the missing return EMPTY is not the cause, thanks anyways.
the accessToken is present on the server. but its not present on the client.

but i could send the request:
this.auth.requestServer(ServerMethod.GET, '/refresh').subscribe()
like this without the refresh logic in the constructor, then the token gets send and would also be present on the client. thats what is so confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT answered my question:

It's possible that the problem lies with the switchMap operator in the router.events observable. The switchMap operator cancels the previous inner observable when a new value is emitted, which could result in the HTTP request being cancelled if it takes too long to complete.

To ensure that the HTTP request is not cancelled, you can try using the concatMap operator instead of switchMap. concatMap will wait for the previous observable to complete before starting a new one, which will prevent the HTTP request from being cancelled prematurely.

Thanks ChatGPT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).